# I got error while creating virtual environment in django

Tags: django, django-views

While creating a virtual environment in Django I got site-package is not writable  and that's why when i write command of Django-admin so i got error not found in external or internal can anyone how I solve this

```sh
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Error: Could not find a version that satifies the requirement virtualenvwrapper-win (from versions: none)
Error: No matching distribution found for virtualenvwrapper-win
```

[image: shell image]

Answer (score 0):

i think virtual environment will be downloaded, if you installed python. Just write

```
python -m venv venv
```

in your cmd.